# Checkbox not working in Gridview to change color - Error Object not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview (ASP.NET  C#) that currently changes color based on dates provided by the user.  Past Due is Red, Future or Current Date is white (Which Works Nicely!).  I have also provided a checkbox in the gridview cell that designates "Complete".  If that checkbox is checked, i want it to override and dates and change the cell color to Black.  So far the error i keep getting is "Object not set to an instance of an object chk was null"

ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
     GridView1_RowUpdating="true" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowUpdating="Page_Load"
     BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid"
     BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black"
     OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Verify Info Prod & Maturity Level" SortExpression="IPMaturity">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IPMaturity", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Width="75"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Complete" Enabled="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" 
                     Checked='<%# Bind ("CheckBox1") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblIPMat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IPMaturity", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Width="75"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="verticaltext" Height="140px" Width="88px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

C# code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
      if (chk.Checked == true)
    {
      e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }
    else
    {
      string ipMaturity = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IPMaturity"));
      DateTime? date1 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipMaturity) ? Convert.ToDateTime(ipMaturity) : (DateTime?)null;

    if (date1.HasValue && date1 >= DateTime.Now)
      e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

    if (date1.HasValue && date1 < DateTime.Now)
      e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
  }
```

Comment: I need the CheckBox to work first before it reads the code related to the Date in ipMaturity.  It keeps throwing an error "Object Not set to an instance of an object" I do not know how to fix this please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gridview Cell Color needs to change based on CheckBox checked in asp.net/c# keep getting errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65544387/gridview-cell-color-needs-to-change-based-on-checkbox-checked-in-asp-net-c-keep)

Comment: Please don't double-post. Add your comment to the original question.

Comment: It doesnt.  I reset my original code and reposted with the error i get. Hoping to get an answer based off my original code.  I can see now how the other way i did it created some confusion.

Comment: Which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: if (chk.Checked == true)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I needed to add the Checkbox to the item template to make sure it shows up after saving/editing.  Then i needed to deal with the Null in C#

ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            GridView1_RowUpdating="true" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowUpdating="Page_Load"
            BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid"
            BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black"
            OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                
               
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Verify Info Prod & Maturity Level" SortExpression="IPMaturity">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IPMaturity", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Width="75"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Complete"  Enabled="true"  
                            Checked='<%# Bind ("CheckBox1") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblIPMat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IPMaturity", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Width="75"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind ("CheckBox1") %>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="verticaltext" Height="140px" Width="88px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

C# Code Behind

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
  
      if (((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1")) != null && ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked)
   
      {
        e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        e.Row.Cells[4].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
      }
      else
     {
        string ipMaturity = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IPMaturity"));
        DateTime? date1 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipMaturity) ?  Convert.ToDateTime(ipMaturity) : (DateTime?)null;

        if (date1.HasValue && date1 >= DateTime.Now)
          e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        if (date1.HasValue && date1 < DateTime.Now)
          e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
      }
```